# Retrieving an array from RESTful api and assigning it to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a website where I have the need for some javascript to retrieve an array from an api returning a json result.

So far I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var json_arr = get_json('http://myurl.com/api/users');
    var users = JSON.parse(json_arr);

    if($.inArray('Joe', users)!==-1)
        howl_at_the_moon('Joe');

}
</script>
```

What should `get_json()` look like for this to work assuming that it can be done?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try. If you face issues, SO is there for your help!

Comment: If you're unsure on whether or not it's working, you could just console.log(users) and see if it's returning the object (not array) that you were expecting?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getjson/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var users = [];
var howl_at_the_moon = function(_user) {
  alert("hi\n" + _user);
};
$.getJSON("http://myurl.com/api/users", function(data) {
    users = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    if($.inArray('Joe', users) !== -1) {
        howl_at_the_moon('Joe');
    };
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/man95w3c/

Comment: getJSON was the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
 var users = [];

 $.ajax({
url : "http://myurl.com/api/users",
type : "get",
dataType: 'json',
success : function(response) {
   users = response;
},
 error: function() {
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use the jQuery getJson like this, as explained in [Api docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```